# Why is MySQL giving me a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, perl

so I am pretty much a big newbie in coding and I am kinda learning by Trial and error, this time I am trying to work with a DB with Perl, actually it works well when I just use 3 table headers (Terminal, Zeitstempel, Ergebnisnummer) but when I try to add more headers (Ergebnistext, Transart, Belegnummer, Trace, Betrag, Kartenart, Kartennummer, Entrymode) it is always giving me a Syntax-error and I checked for half an hour but couldnt find the error. If anyone knows why I would appreciate your help! this part of my code Looks like this:

```
            foreach $file (@file)
        {
            $currentfile = "$currentdir\\$file";
            open(zloop, "<", $currentfile) or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
                    while ( <zloop> ) {
                    my %row;
                    chomp;
                    @row{@headers} = split /;/;
                    my $tid = $row{'tid'}; 
                    my $zeit = $row{'zeit'};
                    my $ergebnisnummer = $row{'ergebnisnummer'};
                    my $ergebnistext = $row{'ergebnistext'};
                    my $transart = $row{'transart'};
                    my $belegnummer = $row{'belegnummer'};
                    my $trace = $row{'trace'};
                    my $betrag = $row{'betrag'};
                    my $kartenart = $row{'kartenart'}; 
                    my $kartennummer = $row{'kartennummer'};
                    my $entrymode = $row{'entrymode'}; 

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `teso`( Terminal, Zeitstempel, Ergebnisnummer, Ergebnistext, Transart, Belegnummer, Trace, Betrag, Kartenart, Kartennummer, Entrymode ) 
    values ( $tid, $zeit, $ergebnisnummer, $ergebnistext, $transart, $belegnummer, $trace, $betrag, $kartenart, $kartennummer, $entrymode )");
    $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
    $sth->finish();
```

i didnt Change the variable names to english because maybe they are causing the Syntax error. This is the error message:

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the m anual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '' )' at line 2 at
>   C:\Users\Desktop\findlogstamp\sqlneu.pl lin e 50,  line 1. You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' )' at
>   line 2 at C:\User s\Desktop\findlogstamp\sqlneu.pl line 50, 
>   line 1.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Building an SQL statement by interpolating variables into a string is generally a very bad idea - See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are possibly getting quotation errors arising from passing your variables in as a string. You should instead use placeholders.

Try doing something like this instead:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `teso`( Terminal, Zeitstempel, Ergebnisnummer, Ergebnistext, 
   Transart, Belegnummer, `Trace`, Betrag, Kartenart, Kartennummer, Entrymode ) 
   values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )');
$sth->execute($tid, $zeit, $ergebnisnummer, $ergebnistext,
   $transart, $belegnummer, $trace, $betrag, $kartenart,
   $kartennummer, $entrymode) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

I've also included [mwp's answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294232/791908).

It is also worth time reading [Borodins Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39295970/791908) for a more thorough way to approach placeholders and SQL inside perl.

Comment: this worked, thank you very much, would you mind explaining what exactly went wrong? my variables are mostly full numbers, but 2-3 are either strings or variant types, i thought marking them with ' ' would be enough

Comment: You will have to quote things precisely for MySQL to be happy processing them. Using bind variables (the `?` in the `prepare()`), and then passing your values to `execute()` will do the "heavy lifting" of quoting where it needs to for you. It's generally the recommended way to pass in variables to statements.

Comment: And for the record, I meant placeholders, not bind variables, they are different things!

Answer (score 3):

I believe "trace" is a reserved word in MySQL. Try adding backticks around the column name(s).

Comment: Wouldn't it figure out that it can only have column names inside of a `INSERT INTO foo ( ... )` construct?

Comment: That would be nice, but unfortunately, no.

Comment: ye, I had an error before that was caused by the column "Terminal-ID", the -ID was causing Problems, took me 1 hour to realize, so i tried putting trace in `` already but it didnt work sadly, thanks for the good answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Values in an SQL expression must be quoted correctly. Simple numeric values don't need quoting, and I imagine the first three columns that you used -- terminal ID, timestamp, and result number -- are all numbers, which is why they worked without quotes

The `DBI` module provides functions database handle method `quote` which will do this for you (as well as `quote_identifier` which does the same thing for identifiers, such as table and column names). However it is always much safer to `prepare` an SQL statement with *placeholders* instead of trying to interpolate the values into the string yourself. Then the actual values can be provided in the `execute` call, wehen `DBI` will implicitly call `$dbh->quote` on all of the values before inserting them into the statement

It is also best to `prepare` a statement just *once*, as the handle may then be used repeatedly. And there is no need to extract a series of scalar variables from your `%row` hash -- a *hash slice* can be used to fetch the correct fields straight from the hash into the `execute` call. It is best, however, to keep a list of the field names in an array as you have done with `@headers`; in fact your `@headers` may be the same as my `@items`, in which case there is no need to define both

I have used a *here document* for the SQL string. If you want to do the same thing then be careful that there must be *no white space* either before or after the end tag `END_SQL` otherwise it won't be found

Note that I've used `join` together with the list repetition operator `x` to produce exactly the right number of question mark placeholders in the QSL. It's much safer to do things this way so as to avoid miscounting, and to allow the number of fields to be changed without altering the SQL statement. You can `print "$sql\n"` to see the SQL that has been built if you wish

I hope this helps

```
my @items = qw/
    tid zeit ergebnisnummer ergebnistext transart
    belegnummer trace betrag kartenart kartennummer entrymode
/;

my $sql = sprintf <<END_SQL, join ', ', ('?') x @items;
INSERT INTO teso (
    Terminal, Zeitstempel, Ergebnisnummer, Ergebnistext, Transart,
    Belegnummer, Trace, Betrag, Kartenart, Kartennummer, Entrymode
)
VALUES (%s)
END_SQL

my $insert = $dbh->prepare($sql);

for my $file ( @file ) {

    my $current_file = "$currentdir\\$file";

    open my $fh, '<', $current_file or die qq{Unable to open "$current_file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        my %row;
        @row{@headers} = split /;/;

        $insert->execute(@row{@items}) or die $sth->errstr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think, error is because backticks around `teso` is interpolated by perl.</strike>
Anyway, interpolating values into a query string is a really bad idea.
You can replace quotation marks around your query with a single quotes (to eliminate undesired interpolation) and replace values to be inserted with a placeholders. Then you should pass actual values to execute() method. Like this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO teso( Terminal, Zeitstempel, Ergebnisnummer, Ergebnistext, Transart, Belegnummer, Trace, Betrag, Kartenart, Kartennummer, Entrymode ) 
values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )');
$sth->execute($tid, $zeit, $ergebnisnummer, $ergebnistext, $transart, $belegnummer, $trace, $betrag, $kartenart, $kartennummer, $entrymode) or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();
```

or, if you wish to insert just a single row, you can replace all this with a single do():

```
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO teso( Terminal, Zeitstempel, Ergebnisnummer, Ergebnistext, Transart, Belegnummer, Trace, Betrag, Kartenart, Kartennummer, Entrymode ) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )', undef,
  $tid, $zeit, $ergebnisnummer, $ergebnistext, $transart, $belegnummer, $trace, $betrag, $kartenart, $kartennummer, $entrymode ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong. Perl does not run anything in backticks tha is inside of the double-quotes. Interpolation does not work that way.

Comment: @simbabque, you're absolutely right! Updated answer.